# How to find EC2 AMI Windows server 2016 KMS host key

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, server

We have a EC2 AMI windows server 2016 running in a VPC with a VPN connection to our office. The windows server currently does AD, DNS etc for the windows 10 desktop environment running in the office. We would like to use this server for Key Management for the windows 10 desktops. The problem we are having is the server requires a KMS Host Key (not the windows 10 KMS key) to setup the KMS service. From my understanding this needs to be a volume licensing KMS key for windows server. Where do I get this information?

I have asked this question on the AWS forum with no response.
Not to be confused with the AWS KMS product.

Answer (score 0):

- Log on to the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://licensing.microsoft.com/) (VLSC).
- Click License.
- Click Relationship Summary.
- Click License ID of the current Active License.
- After the page loads, click Product Keys.
- Look for a key called “Windows Srv 2016 DataCtr/Std KMS”

[Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Help/Contact.aspx)

Comment: Doing this shows me my KMS keys for windows 10.  This server was not purchased through MS.  It was launched and managed from AWS using their Windows Server 2016 Base AMI.

Comment: Do you have a volume license agreement with Microsoft? If not then you cannot use volume license keys. There server OS license does not matter - it is the contract that you need with Microsoft.

Comment: I do for windows 10 Pro.  And I see the KMS keys on the VLS.  I dont for any Server.  I called the Volume license center and he said I would have to purchase Windows Server 2016.  But like I said this is licensed through AWS.  Was that guy wrong?  Can I just get a Volume License for server 2016 without purchasing?  From what I understand previous versions of Windows Server did not require a KMS Host Key (server volume License key) when setting up the KMS service.

Comment: If Microsoft told you that you need to purchase a license ... Remember you did not purchase a Microsoft license from AWS. You are renting an instance with a license. This is not the same thing. Also to use volume licenses on AWS you also need to purchase Software Assurance. Licensing and legal issues are not something that we can help you with on Stack Overflow. Call Microsoft and following their directions. They control / own the licenses.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  Just going to go with MAK licensing for now.